# Edge-maximal graphs of vertex connectivity 2

Tags: graph-theory

What is some characterizing description of what such graphs look like?

By edge-maximal I mean that adding any edge (without increasing the number of vertices) makes the graph 3-vertex-connected.

Comment: $$\overline{K_{m,n}+2K_1}?$$

Comment: What does the bar mean?

Comment: Graph complement.

Comment: Likewise I guess $\overline{K_{m,n}+pK_1}$ is a general expression for an edge-maximal graph of connectivity $p.$ However, I am seriously sleep-deprived, so don't take my word for anything.